# Tables are not getting created for websql in sencha touch app

Tags: sencha-touch-2, web-sql

I have created a sencha touch 2 application, in which I have used websql for offline data storing. There are around 13 tables I am creating using call back function. This works fine on desktop chrome browser. But when I use this application on android tablet, only 6 tables are getting created, but when I restart my app all the tables get created. There no error. Please need help.

Comment: may be its db memory full problem. But can any body give solution for it?

Comment: How to Create WebSQL db in Sencha Touch 2.. When i try i got error like Sql.js file not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple, just needed to increase the memory for db.

Comment: What did you do to increase the db memory?